# What is the difference between the VIVOSUN and VIVOHOME seedling heat mats?

Tags: seedlings, heat

Here are links to the [VIVOSUN](https://smile.amazon.com/VIVOSUN-Waterproof-Seedling-Hydroponic-Standard/dp/B00P7U259C) and [VIVOHOME](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B074MPQ3NF).  They look the same?

Comment: You'd likely get a better answer by asking the manufacturer directly. If they reply, you'd (with any luck) have information to provide an answer yourself.

Comment: I hear you. I asked questions on Amazon as well, which the manufacturer sometimes monitors. I hope to hear back.

Comment: The obvious difference is that you can actually buy one of them, but the other is "unavailable and we don't know when that will change". In fact almost every product on the Vivohome store is unavailable.

Comment: Huh, I actually just bought the VIVOHOME one. So maybe it varies by region.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like the same company, but different broad product lines. One looks more like domestic kitchen stuff and at one time the heat mat was included in that product line, however they decided to expand the line in a particular direction and found that the initial description did not accurately describe what the product did, so they opened up a new product line with a different label that made more sense.